# Use the graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to evaluate $(f+g)(1)$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Use the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to evaluate the following.

[image]

I've done what I think is all the work for this problem, but I'd like to make sure I'm on the right track with this. Feedback on **whether or not I'm correct** would be very helpful.

As far as I know, when you are adding functions (as in part a), you add the $y$-values of a point to get the $y$-value of the new function.

In the same way, when you subtract two functions you subtract the $y$-values, when you are multiplying you multiply the $y$-values, etc. Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking correctly.

- $(f+g)(1) := f(1)+g(1)$
- $(f-g)(5) := f(5)-g(5)$
- $(f/g)(-3) :=    f(-3)/g(-3)$
- $(fg)(5) :=    f(5)g(5)$

Other than this, is just looking at the drawing. After squinting my eyes a bit, I found no mistakes in your work. You're on the right track. Good studies.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Because $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and so on.

These properties can be proven by using limit and continuity. But this requires $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be continuous first.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: What? There is no limits nor continuity involved in this question.

Comment: These assertions are nothing more than the bare definition of the operations between functions..

Comment: For example if $\lim g(1)=+\infty$ so $(f+g)(1)$ cannot be evaluated isn't it? Because $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$